# Secondary fallback/failover network on Cisco ASA

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, failover

In my network there is a Cisco ASA 55x0 with "inside" interface (network 192.168.79.0/24) and "outside" interface (network 89.x.x.48/29)

There is this nat rule:

```
object network NAToutside
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
```

and the static route

```
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 89.x.x.49 1
```

and all ACL rules.
Now I have another new outside network by another ISP called "outside2", this network is already natted and the Cisco ASA in in the network 192.168.70.0/24. I would use this network as a fallback one. So I set the nat rule:

```
object network NAToutside2
 nat (inside,outside2) dynamic interface
```

and the static route with a different metric

```
route outside2 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.70.1 2
```

Clearly it doesn't work: when I disconnect the outside ethernet cable no workstation can connect to the Internet throught the outside2 network... What do I need more?

Comment: Does that other upstream network permit this conversation?

Comment: Does the upstream device attached to outside2 have routes back?  If you do a capture test does it show the traffic as leaving the outside2 interface NAT'd?

Comment: Are you sure your next hop IP is correct - 192.168.70.1?  You'd be NAT'ing your internal traffic to another non-global IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! In Cisco each static route cannot is always active, the only way to use a failover secondary route is using a SLA.

It is explained here:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a00806e880b.shtml

Comment: I follow the procedure but I get another problem http://serverfault.com/questions/520912/cisco-asa-failover-cant-ping-gateway