# Cisco ASA failover can't ping gateway

Tags: cisco-asa, ping, failover

I'm currently trying to set up a failover network for my Cisco ASA 55x0 using the SLA traking. I have the "outside" interface (network 89.x.x.48/29) and the "outside2" interface (network 192.168.70.0/24).

```
  track 1 rtr 1 reachability
  sla monitor 1
    type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 89.x.x.49 interface outside
  sla monitor  schedule 1 start-time now life forever
  route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 89.x.x.49 128  track 1
```

As you can see I set up the ping on IP 89.x.x.49, this one reply when I try to ping from my computer that is in the "inside" network:

```
$ ping 89.x.x.49

Pinging 89.x.x.49 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 89.x.x.49: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
Reply from 89.x.x.49: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
Reply from 89.x.x.49: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
Reply from 89.x.x.49: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255

Ping statistics for 89.x.x.49:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

[image: The problem]

In the picture there is my problem: seems there is a rule on the Cisco that block all the echo-replies from the ip 89.x.x.49 to the firewall, despite I can reach it using my computer and it can reply to my computer.

**UPDATE:**

Here the capture on the outside interface, the behavior seems correct, but the Cisco ASA always denies all the echo-replies toward it.
[image: packet capture on "outside"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: the icmp packets were denied.

```
config t
icmp permit 89.x.x 49  255.255.255.255 outside
```